# Remove redundant characters from string after importing a file

Tags: c#

I'm working on application where my goal is to import a data from .txt file and store it in database.

One row in that file looks like this: [.txt file for import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhWUQ.png)

Lets take a look at "Papua New Guinea" which I marked with red square in the previous image.

So after importing this file using IFormFile I get something like this: [List of items in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEswR.png)

My plan is to store this values to database, but I am having redudant characters as can be seen in previous picture "\"Papua New Guinea\"".

How can I remove those redudant characters? Having in mind that not every item will have those redudant (\") characters (2nd image you can see some integer values)

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using to import the file?

Comment: The slashes are escape characters, right? Not redundant then.

Comment: Those are escape characters for the `"` inside a `"`. They won't show up in the actual output.

Comment: They are in the output. Printed the string and those slashes still were there. Added item in DB with hope they will disappear but they were still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\` is used as escape character to show you that the following `"` does not mark the end of the string but is that it is part of it. The escape character is not part of the string. I.e., in `"\"Papua New Guinea\""`, the string begins with the characters  `"`, `P`, `a` and ends with `e`, `a`, `"`.

You can use an overload of `Trim` accepting characters to be trimmed from the beginning and the end of the string.

```
string s = "\"Papua New Guinea\"";
string trimmed = s.Trim('"');
```

Note that since character literals are delimited with single quotes, you can specify the double quote character without escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Those slashes wont' actually show up if you try to print or do anything with the string.  They're just there because strings start with a " and \" is a way of adding a quotation mark to a string.  Just like \n adds a new line.  The integers don't have them because they don't include a quotation mark.

Comment: I thought the same way as you, printed the string and those slashes still were there. Added item in DB with hope they will disappear but they were still present.